# PyCharm navigating to library source - difference between Typeshed Stubs\unittest and standard Python37\Lib\unittest

Tags: python, pycharm

On two different machines with PyCharm I have the same project.
I have simple code:

```
import unittest
from tests import test

unittest.makeSuite(test)
```

In one case everything is OK - I can navigate to `makeSuite` method without problem, and is properly recognized.

In other case (on different machine) PyCharm not recognizing `makeSuite`

[image]

I understand the problem: source of `unittest` is pointed to the `External Libraries\Python 3.7\Typeshed Stubs\3\unittest`

[image]

Code working fine, just wondering what is the logic behind using Typeshed Stubs what makes some things harder and how I can fix that.

Comment: Are PyCharm versions same on those machines? Stubs for `unittest` have been enabled since 2018.3. PyCharm takes package/module structure and type hints from them. You could navigate to source code by the icon on the gutter, see [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html#stub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comment under my answer I checked versions of PyCharm environments an indeed:
Updating to the newest PyCharm Community (in my case 2018.3.5) cause this bug.

So solution is to downgrade PyCharm to 2018.1

There is also bug created on official PyCharm bug tracking site:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32888

Answer (score 0):

Try from menu: **File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart**

Comment: Sorry, it not helped :(